# Can I capture reboot errors on a system that lives in memory?

Tags: rhel, boot, dmesg

I have a machine that will intermittently experience boot issues and the system will hang and won't come up.  I would normally go to check `dmesg`, but the problem is the system lives in memory and gets re-installed on every reboot, thus wiping the buffer.

Is there a way to capture errors from this situation? Sending data over a link during boot time?

Comment: What kind of hardware is it running on? Many PC BIOSes let you redirect console output to a serial port.